# Formula for finding angle on circle between 2 objects ( with both x,y coordinates )

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

I'm trying to find the angle of a circle(2d)  where I intersect with another (2d)object

I have a spaceship and a planet, I know what the X and Y coordinates are of both.
Now i need to know what the angle/degree is of the planet WHERE the spaceship intersected with the planet.

Thanks in advance.

,Cheers

Ozcan

Comment: The space ship is just a point?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question... Two points cannot "intersect".  But the path that the spaceship takes could intersect with the planet's orbit--is that what you mean?  What is the "circle" you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

If the origin is at (0, 0), the angle (in radians) would be calculated like this:

```
int deltaX = planet.centerX - spaceship.centerX;
int deltaY = planet.centerY - spaceship.centerY;
double radians = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
```

Comment: Yes the planet is the circle and spaceship is the object..

@olavi.. Ill try to implement this in my code to see if it works..
Thanks :)

Comment: @IMP1 in the future, it may be better to notify the author with a comment that there is a potential error in their code. :^)

Comment: @ialarmedalien SO told me about the edit suggestion :)